# How to draw a Feynman diagram in Latex?

Tags: latex

I am trying to draw a Feynman diagram(see attached pic.) using Latex package. But I could not resolve it since two circles I had to draw after the end of the two horizontal lines.
Could you please provide me a snippet of the code on how to draw this Feynman diagram?

[image]

Comment: Please show us some the code you already have. I'm sure we can then help you draw your circles.